# Fun proofs for layperson?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I'm not quite sure whether this question belongs here, because it has no definite answer. But I'll give it a shot. If any of the mods objects, then I will, of course, respectfully delete this contribution.

A friend of mine, who knows a little arithmetic and only the bare rudiments of algebra, has asked me to explain what it is exactly what mathematicians do. Also, she wants to know what a mathematical proof is.

Now I have this idea of presenting her with two sorts of mathematical 'artefacts':

A. A few non-trivial (and preferably striking or beautiful) theorems whose proofs are easy and brief enough for my friend to understand. Euclid's proof of the infinitude of the primes, or Cantor's of the uncountability of the real numbers, would fit this category. But I would like something a bit off the beaten track, that's not been done to death in thousands of `popular' books.

B. A couple of results whose proofs are not neccesarily easy, but which illustrate nicely how mathematicians deal with heuristics and with discovering new theorems. A few immediately plausible yet striking conjectures would be nice, too. Unfortunately, I can't think of any concrete examples from the top of my head right now. (Edit: the four color theorem comes to mind.)

Your suggestions will be warmly appreciated.

Comment: You want something off the beaten track to amuse yourself? Or is that goal, in some way that I'm missing, in service to answering your friend's query?

Comment: Well, maybe there's something even nicer than Euclid's or Cantor's proofs.

Comment: Presumably, there's a reason they are covered in almost all efforts to introduce proofs, however. Sometimes the time-tested really are the best. (Although I don't think dealing with infinity is easy for a person with arithmetic, so I'd skip Cantor.)

Comment: I like the four square theorem as something one can quickly conjecture but can't be easily proved.

Comment: You have a point, of course. Still, the more examples to choose from the merrier. Edit: thanks, the four square theorem is excellent.

Comment: How about solving classical problems of Greek geometry using Galois theory. The geometric problems are easy to grasp, and this demonstrates the power of modern ideas in algebra.

Comment: The Jordan curve theorem. An elementary proof in the case of a polygonal line is given in the book *What is mathematics*? Obviously, it is hard to state the general theorem for a layperson, since one needs to know what a continuous function is.

Comment: There are a number of pictorial "proofs" for important infinite series related to Zeno's paradoxes. Have a look at $<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF">wikipedia</a>.$  Sorry, apparently I don't know how to embed a link in a comment.  Seriously.

Comment: Thanks all! The Jordan curve theorem is nice, because it can be used as a starting point for the question why there is a need to prove things that are so 'obvious'.

Comment: I've been revisiting some basic analysis. The progression from the definition of a continuous function; the preservation of sign for a continuous function; Bolzano's theorem; and ending with the Intermediate value theorem is not at all complex and illustrates how a theory can be developed.

Comment: A good resource for this would be [cut the knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/). [Breaking a Chocolate Bar](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/chocolad.shtml) might appeal.

Answer (score 5):

Something easily grasped by pretty much anyone are problems related to covering chessboards with dominoes. (I'm especially fond of these because learning about them was what initially got me interested in mathematics.)

A domino exactly covers two squares of chessboard.  Can you always cover an $8\times 8$ chessboard with dominoes?  Of course this is easy by just placing four dominoes in each row.  (We always assume a sufficient supply of dominoes, in this case, $32$.)

But what if we remove two squares from opposite corners of the chessboard; can we still cover it with $31$ dominoes?  In this case the answer is no, because opposite corner squares have the same colour (black, or white as shown below), which means that there are $32$ squares of one colour and $30$ of the other, while each domino covers two squares of different colours.

[image: "Mutilated checkerboard 3" by DavidHardman]

There are many other problems of this sort involving covering pruned chessboards with dominoes (or other so-called "polyominoes"), some of which have simple, easily explained proofs like the one above. (Though perhaps not quite *that* simple.)

There is a nice [book](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7714.html) of chessboard problems by John J. Watkins that includes proof of some of these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2):

A useful introduction to proof by induction is to take a $2 \times 2$ square with one corner removed as in the diagram below.

[image: The basic building block]

The problem is to prove that using these shapes, one can cover any $2^n \times 2^n$ square with one corner removed as in the next diagram.

[image: The 4x4 space]

Answer (score 1):

[Circle division by chords](http://weitz.de/math/) is also a nice one IMHO.  It is easy to explain, it shows that you shouldn't make assumptions too early, and the proof of the correct formula can be understood with high school algebra.

[image]

[Picture from [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyChords.html).]